# Reassigning deprecated properties to new properties objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I've got a property that I want to change the name of. Basically I want the old property to return/set the value of the new property so existing code doesn't break, but it'll throw warnings to use the new name.

This is in my header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyClass *newProperty;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyClass *oldProperty __attribute__((deprecated));
```

To make oldProperty's getters and setters just set/return newProperty's values in the implementation i'd like to do something like

```
@synthesize oldProperty=_newProperty;
```

This throws an error 'oldProperty and newProperty both claim instance variable _newProperty'. Whats the best way to achieve what I want to do? (I'm deprecating and renaming about 30 properties)

Setting the getters/setters manually returns the same error

```
- (void)setOldProperty:(MyClass *)oldProperty {
    _newProperty=oldProperty;
}

- (MyClass *)oldProperty:(MyClass *)oldProperty {
    return _newProperty;
}
```

**EDIT: Solution I used with the help of BlackRiders input -------------------------------------------------------------**

Interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyClass *newProperty;
- (void)setOldProperty:(MyClass *)oldProperty __attribute__((deprecated));
- (MyClass *)oldProperty __attribute__((deprecated));
```

Implementation:

```
- (void)setOldProperty:(MyClass *)oldProperty {
    _newProperty=oldProperty;
}

- (MyClass *)oldProperty {
    return _newProperty;
}
```

Comment: Refactor to remove all references to the old property...

Comment: This is in a framework that is being used in multiple projects by multiple developers. Thats not really an option I can control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have just one actual property to avoid confusion and name collisions. For example:

```
property (getter=oldProperty, setter=setOldProperty:) MyClass *newProperty;
```

You can also optionally create the methods `newProperty` and `setNewProperty:`. You can also throw in some `#warning` statements in the getter and setter you want people to stop using.

Comment: Any reason you can think of why I wouldn't do @property (getter=newProperty, setter=setNewProperty:) MyClass *oldProperty. That way I can use the new setters if I want instead of having the old ones lying around still? Seems like what you said works though!

Comment: That works too, of course :) Or just declare `newProperty` normally, with the default accessors, and create methods `oldProperty` and `setOldProperty:` and throw a warning inside them.

Comment: A small problem with this solution is, an instance variable is still created by automatic synthesis. Not a "big" problem, but you should be aware. Also this can break KVO and KVC if implemented incorrectly. In short, I would not risk it.

Comment: It's a valid point, but I think KVO may break with any solution involving 2 properties (or one property and two pairs of getters and setters).

Comment: What about the way that I solved it in my edit to the question? That doesn't have any problems with KVO correct?